# Downloading from dropbox url ignores range

Tags: java, android, http, dropbox, httpconnection

If i want to download a file from a dropbox url my http header range is ignored:

```
httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
httpRequest.addHeader("Range", "bytes=" + startPos + "-"    + dwnInfo.getStopRange());
httpRequest.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "");
```

So instead of making my file download in x chunks of 5mb for ex, the connection ignores the specified range and it downloads x chunks of Y mb, where y is the full size of the file.

Downloading from an amazon storange link i don't have any problems.

Anyone else encountered this situation ? This only happens from some days ago. This wasn't a issue until now.

I tried to look on dropbox dev page but didn't see anything that specifies if they removed the accepted range on urls

Comment: Dropbox generally supports range retrieval both in the API and in downloadable share links. What kind of URL are you reading from? (Can you give an example or at least say how you created/acquired the URL?)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5c7atlfmacjf3qn/02%20Armin%20Van%20Buuren%20-%20A%20State%20Of%20Trance%20Year%20Mix%202013%20%28Cd%202%29.mp3

Comment: checked and it doesn't return 206 .. it returns 200, so my guess is that it doesn't support range anymore on those links

Comment: https://twitter.com/jakubroztocil/status/435392335342362624

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you gave is to an HTML page (total size ~46KB), so even if range retrieval worked there, it wouldn't be very useful.

Per https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en, you can turn a share link into a direct link to the file by changing the domain to `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`, so your link becomes https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5c7atlfmacjf3qn/02%20Armin%20Van%20Buuren%20-%20A%20State%20Of%20Trance%20Year%20Mix%202013%20%28Cd%202%29.mp3, and range retrieval works for that URL.

(Here I'm using [httpie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie).)

```
$ http get https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5c7atlfmacjf3qn/02%20Armin%20Van%20Buuren%20-%20A%20State%20Of%20Trance%20Year%20Mix%202013%20%28Cd%202%29.mp3 range:bytes=0-0
HTTP/1.1 206 PARTIAL CONTENT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Date: Wed, 18 Jun 2014 14:53:32 GMT
Server: nginx
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=0
content-range: bytes 0-0/146014047
etag: 346n
pragma: public
set-cookie: uc_session=2cqmevWxG8lmGt743KMXebc23dRC5iuZEfm8Etx6V2VShWk60jmnUJajFnH1wRG4; Domain=dropboxusercontent.com; Path=/; secure; httponly
x-dropbox-request-id: 2f0c5986a62cf2f0b06af1704ece5bd7
x-server-response-time: 535

I
```

Comment: i will check and get back to you, thanks. If it will work will for any link i will accept the amswer

Comment: to make the file download i need to add ?dl=1. This makes the new link to not accept partial content :(

Comment: No, you don't need to add `?dl=1`. Are you having some trouble with the exact URL I gave you?

Comment: yes ... it only downloads like 300kb, not all the file

Comment: What tool/code are you using to download the file? "http -d get https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5c7atlfmacjf3qn/02%20Armin%20Van%20Buuren%20-%20A%20State%20Of%20Trance%20Year%20Mix%202013%20%28Cd%202%29.mp3" gives me a 139.25 MB file (146014047 bytes).